# Call stored procedure from stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i'm new to MySQL.
I need to call stored procedure from a stored procedure and use the first stored procedure as a table.
How to do this without use temporary table?

Comment: It depends on if the stored procedure is a function, or a resultset. If it is a function, you can just call it the way you would call it in normal SQL, however if it is a resultset, you may need to define a temporary table (in-memory like a variable) to process it.  I am not sure if you can pass a table to a stored procedure though.

Answer (score 0):

> How to do this without use temporary table?

**create a fact table then**

Not sure why there is a requirement saying: can't use temporary table as you are using store procedure.  but that must be unreasonable.

if the RDBS takes care of that for you , the underlying mechanism is still store the 1st result set somewhere in the memory as middle step result. `temporary table` for you.

so just: create a temporary table, call the store procedure, insert data into that . why not

Comment: In my Stored Procedure I have the next lines: